# Upgrade Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 Without the Button in Update Manager

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, upgrade

I would like to Upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04. I read the instructions, but the "Upgrade"-Button didnt occur within my Update Manager Window.

Is there another way to upgrade?

would be delighted for your support!

Enjoy your day! Co.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/q/91815/65926)

Answer (score 1):

The Update Manager takes command-line options:

```
user@host:~$ update-manager --help
Usage: update-manager [options]                                                                                         

Options:                                                                                                                
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit                                                                 
  -V, --version         Show version and exit                                                                           
  --data-dir=DATA_DIR   Directory that contains the data files                                                          
  -c, --check-dist-upgrades                                                                                             
                        Check if a new Ubuntu release is available                                                      
  -d, --devel-release   Check if upgrading to the latest devel release is                                               
                        possible                                                                                        
  -p, --proposed        Upgrade using the latest proposed version of the                                                
                        release upgrader
  --no-focus-on-map     Do not focus on map when starting
  --dist-upgrade        Try to run a dist-upgrade
  --no-update           Do not check for updates when starting
  -s, --sandbox         Test upgrade with a sandbox aufs overlay
```

In particular, running `update-manager --dist-upgrade` brings up the distribution upgrade window.

Comment: Hi! I also have the same problem. There isn't an "Upgrade" button. I've just tried to use the options of update-manager but it says that it cannot upgrade. I use 11.10 on Dell notebook (Ubuntu is pre-installed).